# Getting Null value while parsing the XML string in C#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, datacontractserializer, xml-deserialization

Trying to parse XML String in C# where in SessionId i am getting the null value. while pasing the value approx everything is coming correctly, just session id is null every time. every other field is coming and being parsed very well. i just got the null value with the session id part. i tried to do this with JSON also but its not getting done. finally data.SessionId is null.

```
namespace EmailToActivityCreator
{

[DataContract]
public class EmailInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CCMail { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmailState { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FromEmail { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ToEmail { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String arguments = args[0];
        //Console.Error.Write(arguments);

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(arguments);
        EmailInfo data;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(EmailInfo));
            data = (EmailInfo)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
```

and the value we are passing is something like this

```
"<EmailInfo xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC\">
<Body>&lt;div dir=&quot;ltr&quot;&gt;body
&lt;/div&gt;
</Body>
<CCMail></CCMail>
<EmailState>Received</EmailState>
<FromEmail>Ravi Ranjan &lt;ravi.ranjan@xyz.com&gt;</FromEmail>
<Subject>subject</Subject>
<ToEmail> &lt;ravi@eras.in&gt;</ToEmail>
<SessionId>sss</SessionId>
</EmailInfo>"
```

Comment: Does your class have a SessionId property?

Comment: Your class is missing the appropriate property... I don't see any `SessionId`.

Comment: yup, i know in written code here, i wrote test. but in my class i have

Comment: No. i have in my code. anyway i edited. i was taking other variable name and experimenting on it. bt it not working.

Comment: @Arunster  do you have any idea about it??

Comment: @germi do you have any idea??

Comment: working with 32bit visual studio 2010

Comment: I played around a bit and don't really know where the problem's coming from, but: If you can reorder the XML-Elements in the following order, it works for me: `EmailInfo` > `Body` > `CCMail` > `EmailState` > `FromEmail` > `SessionId` > `Subject` > `ToEmail`

Comment: thaks @germi i will try and will get back to you. :)

Comment: @germi its working. thaks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

`DataContractSerializer` *requires* the elements in the XML to be in the same order as the [data member order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx) in the [data contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Elements in the wrong order will be *ignored* ([reference 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a891928b-d27a-4ef2-83b3-ee407c6b9187/order-of-data-members-in-the-xml-string-influences-deserialization-datacontractserializer?forum=wcf), [reference 2](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/08/wcf-be-ware-of-the-field-ordering-when-using-datacontractserializer/)).  The default order is given here: [Data Member Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx).

> The basic rules for data ordering include:
>
> - If a data contract type is a part of an inheritance hierarchy, data members of its base types are always first in the order.
> - Next in order are the current type’s data members that do not have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set, in alphabetical order.
> - Next are any data members that have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set. These are ordered by the value of the Order property first and then alphabetically if there is more than one member of a certain Order value. Order values may be skipped.
>
> Alphabetical order is established by calling the CompareOrdinal method.

You may specify the order in which the XML elements will be encountered using the [`DataMemberAttribute.Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC")] // The namespace you used.
public class EmailInfo
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string CCMail { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string EmailState { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string FromEmail { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string ToEmail { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

If your code is required to read XML with elements in any order, you must either implement [`IXmlSerializable`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly) yourself (a nuisance), or switch to another serializer such as [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).